# If $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function with compact support. Then $f$ is continuous differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is it true that if $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function with compact support. Then $f$ is continuous differentiable.

Comment: No, this is false. Remember: under these assumptions there is no difference between $\Bbb{R}^2$ and $\Bbb{C}$, so you can construct a counterexample using two variables $x,y$. Find a function $g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ continuous with compact support which is not differentiable, and then define $f(x,y)=g(x)g(y)$.

Comment: Alright thank you. Crostul